# How to fix ‘items.map is not define’ error in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm just new developer about reactjs

I'm try to map data.I am following reactjs tutorial and this is my result, but i trying and trying again is it not working. How can i solve is ??

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
 // API from reqres
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.data);
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.data
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
//this is the problem
          {items.map(item=> { 
            return <div>
              <p>{item.id}</p>
            </div>
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Please help me, I just want to view my data :(

After I change fetch to Axios i have the same problem ??

```
    Axios({
      method:"GET",
      url:"https://reqres.in/api/users"
    }).then(res => {
      this.setState({
         isLoaded:true,
           items: res.data
      })
      console.log(res.data)

  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)

  })
```

Comment: Can you log what items is within the render function and tell us the result?

Comment: Return data from https://reqres.in/api/users/2 is not array. `data` is object. The map method is for Array.

Comment: thank kkangil, but what is for my api ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Fetch data from `"https://reqres.in/api/users"` and use that data, becouse /users returns array of users,and /users/2 returns user object for userId=2.

Comment: I see my problem then, tks ivica.moke a lot :))

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by giving items a default value:

```
const { error, isLoaded, items = [] } = this.state;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://reqres.in/api/users/2

This is the response data from server

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
  }
}
```

If you can change the server, change data result to array.
It's gonna works well.

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
  }]
}
```

But you can't change the response data, you can't use with `.map`

```
render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
//just use for one(object)
            <div>
              <p>{item.id}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```